# If $R'$ is set of all reals except zero and $a*b = |a|b$, then is $(R',*)$ a group?

Tags: group-theory

Let $R'$ be set of all real numbers **except zero**. Define a binary operation $*$ 
 such that $a*b = |a|b$, where $|a|$ denotes the absolute value of $a$. Does $(R'*)$ form a group?

My attempt:

1 is the identity. But here $-2*1 = 2$

So can we say it is not a group?

Comment: "1 is identity. But here $-2*1 = 2$" But then $1$ _isn't_ idrentity, since you've just found a counterexample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 is the identity of the real numbers under standard multiplication, but since you are not using standard multiplication, then you could imagine that some other real number $\lambda$ could be the identity. However, that number would need to satisfy:

$-2 * \lambda = -2$ and $2 * \lambda = 2$.

but then, $2\lambda = -2$ and $2\lambda = 2$. Clearly, no real number satisfies both of these properties, so it is not a group.

Comment: +1. Note to the OP that merely saying "$1$ *looks like* it should be the identity, but it's not" isn't enough to conclude that the structure isn't a group; it's always possible that some *other* element could be the identity. To show that it's not a group, you need to show that *no element at all* is the identity, which is what this answer does.

Comment: thank you sir, got it

Answer (score 4):

Mostly.

The identity is *not* $1$ but you have to prove that it can't be anything else.

Let $e \in R'$

If $e > 0$ let $a \in R'; a < 0$ then $|a|e > 0$ so $|a|e$ is not the identity.

If $e < 0$ let $a \in R'; a > 0$  then $|a|e < 0$ so $|a|e$ is not the identity.

So it is not possible for any arbitrary $e$ to be the identity.

So there is no identity.

====

Alternatively, to give the OP a little more credit (perhaps more than is actually there)

One could say:

Suppose there were an identity.

Then $|2|*e = 2$ so that would mean $e= 1$ and therefore $1$ is the only possible candidate to be the identity.

But $|-2|*1 \ne -2$.  So it is not the identity.  So there is not identity.

To claim "$1$ is the identity", which I'm leniently going to accept as meaning "$1$ should be the identity", one does have to explain why one thinks $1$ should be the identity.

Comment: very elaborative. thank you